# Android Things: Any way to PWM on GPIO 20?

Tags: pi-3, gpio, pwm, android-things

I'm playing with a motor board, a PWR.A52.A, that is mapping the ENA and ENB of its L298P to the BCM13 and BCM20.

The problem is that **Android Things** is mapping the PWM to BCM13 and BCM18.

[image]

I don't think there is a software solution to this problem due to Android Things (I have [opened an feature request for this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70115494)), but maybe there is an hardware solution...

Sorry for the silly question but this is not my field: what will happen if I short BCM18 and BCM20 and I <s>keep BCM20 to low</s> set BCM20 as an input and use BCM18 as PWM?

Probably I'm going to damage something, but that's why I'm asking.
[image: short]
This is a graphical representation of what I mean by shorting BCM18 and BCM20.

Is there any other safe and easy solution that can help me with this problem?

This is the pin mapping of the board:

[image: PWR.A53.A pin mapping]
[image: schematics]

Comment: It would  probably be okay if it is set as an *input,* since they are on a high resistance circuit.

Comment: @goldilocks I have tried but didn't work. Probably due to the board internal wiring. I've added a schematic of it (that I can't understand). My try was to connect the PWM0 to the ENB_1 of the board.

Comment: You'd still need to use BCM18 for the hardware connection. Can you stick a probe on that line and see what is being output.

Comment: Sure, that was what I did, I connected the GPIO18 pin of the board, which is connected directly to the BCM18 of the Pi, to the ENB_1 of the board. I have a multimeter and not a lot of experience with electronics, should I just check the voltage or you need something more?

Comment: BTW I wasn't claiming it would work, just that you would at least not be shorting the system.  I am a bit surprised it doesn't though, since set as an input the pin is basically a just a piece of metal.

Comment: Can it be due to that CON1-A thing in the schematics? because, if I got it right, I'm connecting it to the ENB_1 and not directly to the ENB...

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is still no way to have *hardware PWM* on pins different from `BCM13` and `BCM18`, but I wrote a *software PWM* library that works on any GPIO pin, allows frequencies up to 300 Hz and is good enough to control a DC motor via L298, if the accuracy of the speed is not that important.

The library is published on JCenter. Source and info: https://github.com/leinardi/androidthings-pio/tree/master/pio-softpwm

Answer (score 0):

You can use software timed PWM on all accessible GPIO.  That will have some jitter but may be good enough for your usage.

You can also use hardware timed PWM on all accessible GPIO.  Have a look at (my) [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html), or servoblaster, or the RPIO.GPIO module (not RPi.GPIO which is software timed PWM only).

Comment: hey, probably I should have put more emphases on the OS I'm using: it's Android Things, so I can't use those libraries. But thanks anyway.

Comment: You could still use pigpio as long as Android Things supports Python.  The pigpio Python module runs okay on my Android based phone.

Comment: AFAIK python isn't available out of the box on Android Things and currently I'm looking for solutions that don't require for the user any additional configuration step beside installing the Apk on the Pi.

Comment: @RobertoLeinardi Might be useful to update the question line to mention Android things.  There are lots of ways to provide PWM on GPIO20 in other operating systems.

Comment: Android Things doesn't support python, but OP could probably port your library to Android as it probably won't be too difficult.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that such a port won't be possible in the Android sandboxed user space, using only the exposed Android Things API, so it must be part of the Android Things framework, and integrated directly in the OS. Unfortunately I don't think will be that easy (for me), and it would be not just writing a working library, but also get it merged to the AOSP code by Google...

Comment: @joan I made a first attempt on creating a software PWM for Android Things, every feedback that can help improving it is very welcome: [source](https://github.com/leinardi/androidthings-kuman-sm9/blob/6acc048c79b4d58b424455b674cf116823dc27ab/pwra53a/src/main/java/com/leinardi/androidthings/pio/SoftPwm.java)